# Freezes if desktop effects is used

Tags: xorg

I have found that using desktop effects in Ubuntu versions later than 8.10 causes the desktop to freeze after a few seconds on my PC. the command `lspci -nn` gave the following

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2772] (rev 02)
```

and with `lspci -k` I have

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
```

The intel graphics cards seems to have some performence issues with xorg driver. 
However I have not noticed any freeze in Ubuntu 8.10.

There are some workarounds at [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Bugs/Lucidi8xxFreezes](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Bugs/Lucidi8xxFreezes) to make them work. But I can't find out what workaround should I do with my graphics controller. I have tried workaround F but it did not help.

can anyone help me find a workaround for my graphics card?
and
is it actually possible to use desktop effect in this graphics card ?

Comment: What Ubuntu version you are using now? 10.04, 10.10? Problem still persists?

Comment: I am using 10.10. I have also used 10.04. the problem still persists !

Comment: is there anybody who can help ? I am waiting for two days for any answer...

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score -1):

Disable the desktop effects:

We have three computers with the same chipset and the very same problem at work.

20 PCs, 3 of them with the intel 945 chipset... the three of them have issues. They constantly freeze. We tried to boot in Ubuntu Classic, but it doesn't change anything.

Just stick to 10.04 and disable the desktop effects.